# Duplicate code removal strategy in a legacy project

Tags: c++, polymorphism, variant

I recently started working on a legacy project. I could see a lot of code duplication of the format below:

```
void somefunc(arg1,arg2,Type1 * Ptr) 
{
      //some logic
}
```

//overloaded on Type2

```
void somefunc(arg1,arg2,Type2 * Ptr) 
{
         //same logic
}
```

> The only difference between the two functions are the **type of the
>   third argument**. **Type1 and Type2** are derived from **Type**.

Type is determined at runtime. So i tried something like this

```
void somefunc(arg1,arg2,Type * Ptr) 
{
    if (arg1.version > 14) 
        Type1 *ptr = dynamic_cast<Type1*>(Ptr);
    else
        Type2 *ptr = dynamic_cast<Type2*>(Ptr);

    //some logic using ptr
}
```

But it requires a dynamic_cast to determine the correct type at runtime. And I have to update the code in lot of places with if else blocks.

Thought of Boost variant. It appears similar to the above approach.

Is there a simpler/elegant way to avoid this kind of code duplication ?

Comment: If you have polymorphic classes and you need to differentiate with dynamic_cast, perhaps your design is wrong. You could add sample declarations to your question.

Comment: Also you can avoid the need for the `dynamic_cast<>`  you can make `Type` a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), that would be _static polymorphism_ then, and all is determined at compile time.

Comment: @DeiDei Well, TBF such kind of design flaws is often found with legacy code.

Comment: Please format your code blocks properly and use actual c++ syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simpler/elegant way to avoid this kind of code duplication ?

The easiest approach would be to make `somefunc()` a template function:

```
template <typename T>
void somefunc(arg1,arg2,T* Ptr) 
{
      //some logic
}
```

Thus you can call `somefunc()` with either `Type1` or `Type2` without need to determine these using `dynamic_cast<>`:

```
Type1 a;
Type2 b;

somefunc(x,y,&a); // Uses Type1
somefunc(x,y,&b); // Uses Type2
```

---

> Type is determined at runtime. So i tried something like this
>
> ```
> void somefunc(arg1,arg2,Type * Ptr) 
> {
>     if (arg1.version > 14) 
>         Type1 *ptr = dynamic_cast<Type1*>(Ptr);
>     else
>         Type2 *ptr = dynamic_cast<Type2*>(Ptr);
>
>     //some logic using ptr
> }
> ```

This can't ever work, since `ptr` is declared only visible in the `if` / `else` scope blocks, and you would need to duplicate the logic again.